# How do I get the missing information from a table by comparing with another table in sql using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of configuration table of roles that a person can have

| Seq | Role | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | Add |
| 2 | Admin | Delete |
| 3 | Admin | Edit |
| 4 | Coordinator | Add |

I also have a list of users with some missing functions

| Seq | Users | Role | Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Howard | Admin | Add |
| 2 | Howard | Admin | Remove |
| 3 | Sheldon | Admin | Add |
| 4 | Sheldon | Admin | Edit |

As you can see, howard is missing the admin-edit function and sheldon is missing admin-delete function.

How do I write a query to get the missing functions for each user by comparing the config table with the user table?

Expected result:

| Seq | Users | Role | Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Howard | Admin | Add |
| 2 | Howard | Admin | Remove |
| 3 | null | Admin | Edit |
| 4 | Sheldon | Admin | Add |
| 5 | Sheldon | Admin | Edit |
| 6 | null | Admin | Remove |

Is there also a way to directly get missing function with a user attached from the tables?

Missing roles:

| Seq | Users | Role | Function |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Howard | Admin | Edit |
| 6 | Sheldon | Admin | Remove |

Comment: you should have the same functions in users and roles

Comment: and a coordinator and admin are the same role?

Comment: They are different roles, coordinators can only add but are unable to delete or edit.
Admin can do all 3.

Comment: Your should (try to) avoid using reserved words, like [ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=INDICATOR-,ROLE,-ALIAS) and  [FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=BETWEEN-,FUNCTION,-RETURN) as column names.

Comment: Why are you duplicating information, just store the User and his role and look up the available functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form a Cartesian product of users/role and possible functions within each role, then left join the existing user_table. any unmatched rows can then be listed. e.g.

```
WITH user_roles AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT u.Users, u.Role
    FROM user_table u
),
role_functions AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Role, [Function]
    FROM config_table
)
SELECT ur.Users, rf.Role, rf.[Function]
FROM user_roles ur
INNER JOIN role_functions rf ON ur.role = rf.role
LEFT JOIN user_table u ON ur.Users = u.Users AND rf.Role = u.Role AND rf.[Function] = u.[Function]
WHERE u.[Function] IS NULL
```

```
CREATE TABLE config_table (
    Seq INTEGER,
    Role varchar(20),
    [Function] varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE user_table (
    Seq INTEGER,
    Users varchar(20),
    Role varchar(20),
    [Function] varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO config_table (Seq, Role, [Function])
VALUES
(1, 'Admin', 'Add'),
(2, 'Admin', 'Remove'),        --<< changed to "Remove"
(3, 'Admin', 'Edit'),
(4, 'Coordinator', 'Add');

INSERT INTO user_table (Seq, Users, Role, [Function])
VALUES
(1, 'Howard', 'Admin', 'Add'),
(2, 'Howard', 'Admin', 'Remove'),
(3, 'Sheldon', 'Admin', 'Add'),
(4, 'Sheldon', 'Admin', 'Edit');
```

| Users | Role | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Howard | Admin | Edit |
| Sheldon | Admin | Remove |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a5uqxCSY)

Answer (score 0):

You can Join then only ny role and exclude all exsting functions

the problem that remve is equal to delete must be adressed, by replacing all mathes

```
SELECT
DISTINCT  u."Users", u."Role",r."Function"
FROM roles r INNer JOIN users u ON r."Role" = u."Role" 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM users  
  WHERe REPLACE("Function",'Remove','Delete')  = r."Function" AND u."Role" = "Role"   AND u."Users" = "Users")
```

| Users | Role | Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Howard | Admin | Edit |
| Sheldon | Admin | Delete |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rBRNJY-t)